# How to check if a Wordpress post date is at least 7 days old

Tags: php, wordpress, date, compare

I´d like to create a function that checks if a "post" (wordpress) is older than 7 days. I have the following code so far:

```
function is_old($start) {

    $now = date("Y-m-d");

}
```

`$start` contains the date which I want to check if is more than 7 days prior to `$now`. How can I do this?

Comment: Its the same format as $now (Y-m-d)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `$start` is a date, this works:

```
function is_old($start) {
    return strtotime($start) < strtotime('-1 week');
}
```

If `$start` is a timestamp, you can omit the first `strtotime`.

Comment: @Espen Arnoy: yes. The return value is the result of a comparison, which is always a boolean.

Answer (score 1):

If `$start` is a timestamp you have just to do

```
$days_old = (time() - $start) / 86400
```